# How to serve documentation using godoc together with go modules?

Tags: go, documentation, documentation-generation, go-modules

It seems that the `godoc` tool is not [Go modules](https://blog.golang.org/modules2019) aware.

A simple `godoc -goroot=.` serves the project files, but it does not generate documentation for the packages. I tested it from withing the projects source directory, where also the `go.mod` and `go.sum` module files are stored.

**How to generate documentation for all packages inside a Go module - outside of `$GOPATH`?**

In the [release notes of *Go 1.12*](https://golang.org/doc/go1.12#godoc) is written that the `godoc` tool will not be included in future Go releases and will only be available via `go get` after *Go 1.12*. One should use the [Go `go doc` command](https://golang.org/cmd/doc/). However, `go doc` does not generate "nice to read" HTML pages. **Is there an alternative for documentation generation from Go source code which outputs HTML or Markdown?**

Comment: "not Go modules aware" meaning what exactly? Modules have no impact on documentation. What do you expected it to be "aware" of in regarding to modules?

Comment: I expected it to generate documentation for Go packages managed with Go modules outside of the GOPATH.

Comment: GOROOT and GOPATH aren't the same. You shouldn't be pointing `-goroot` at your source. GOROOT should be pointing at your Go installation. Also to the last part of your question, requests for third-party tools and libraries are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Related comments on Github: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26827#issuecomment-429315761. That appears to be the issue tracking this (as yet unavailable) feature. See also https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25443#issuecomment-474553586.

Answer (score 9):

The issue isn't modules so much as GOPATH.  There's a github issue thread that discusses this in more detail: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26827

That thread has evolved a workaround that uses a docker container to run a godoc server with GOPATH set to the base of your dev tree.  That godoc server will serve docs for all of the packages in your dev tree, regardless of whether they have a go.mod yet or not.

Here's a version of the workaround that I just posted in that thread this morning -- modify $devbase (or pass it in as $1) to point at the base of your tree:

```
#!/bin/bash 

set -x  # optional

devbase=$HOME/gohack
port=6060

docker run \
    --rm \
    -e "GOPATH=/tmp/go" \
    -p 127.0.0.1:$port:$port \
    -v $devbase:/tmp/go/src/ \
    --name godoc \
    golang \
    bash -c "go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc && echo http://localhost:$port/pkg/ && /tmp/go/bin/godoc -http=:$port"
```

You'll note that I'm also using the [gohack](https://github.com/rogpeppe/gohack) tool -- it manages the 'replace' lines in go.mod for you so imports will find your local version of a module even if it's not pushed to a server yet.  There's otherwise nothing special about $devbase -- pointing it at $HOME/src should work just as well, for instance.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently it has been fixed here https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33655

All I had to do was to upgrade go to version 1.14 and then running `godoc` in my directory with go modules works.

The `godoc` command should run in module mode whenever the `go` command runs in module mode. So `godoc` should run `go env GOMOD` with the same environment and working directory, and interpret the result.

If the result of `go env GOMOD` is an empty string, then `GOPATH` mode is being used, and `godoc` will behave the way it used to with `GOPATH` and it will only look in the `GOPATH` directory.